# How to use apache sling extension gwt servlet 3.0.0?

Tags: gwt, servlets, sling

I have a GWT project(GWT version 2.4). I want to start up Spray-servlet in server side GWT, but GWT does not support servlet-3.0, therefore I wanted to use org.apache.sling.extensions.gwt.servlet-3.0.0.jar for using servlet-3.0.0.

How I can use **org.apache.sling.extensions.gwt.servlet-3.0.0.jar** in GWT?

**EDIT**

If **sling** does not help me, then how can I run **spray-servlet-1.2-RC1** in server side GWT?

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.sling.extensions.gwt.servlet-3.0.0.jar is not a Servlet 3.0 package for GWT, but an extension to Apache [Sling](http://sling.apache.org) meant to allow server-side GWT code to run.

It's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, if sling does not help me, then how can I run spray-servlet-1.2-RC1 in server side GWT?